# Statistics hotel overbooking question

Tags: probability

The question was:

Suppose that a popular hotel for vacationers in Orlando, Florida, has a total of 300 identical rooms. As many major airline companies do, this hotel has adopted an overbooking policy in an effort to maximize the usage of its available lodging capacity. Assume that each potential hotel customer holding a room reservation, independently of other customers, cancels the reservation or simply does not show up at the hotel on a given night with probability $0.15$. What is the probability that on a given night at least $6$ customers do not show up?

I had previously asked for help on another part of this question, but I can't work out where I've gone wrong for this one.

My attempt:

Using binomial

Probability that at least $6$ don't show up: 
\begin{align*}
P(X \geq 6) &= [1- P(X=0) + P(X=1)+ \ldots +P(X=5)] \\
n &= 300 \\
p &= 0.15 \\
q &= 0.85 \\
x &= 0,1,2,3,4,5 \\
&=1-(6.69388 \cdot 10^{-22})+(3.54382 \cdot 10^{-20}+(9.34942 \cdot 10^{-19})+(1.6389  \cdot 10^{-17})+(2.14744 \cdot 10^{-16})+(2.24344 \cdot 10^{-15}) \\
&=0.99999999999999800000000000
\end{align*}

Is my solution correct? I now realise this answer isn't ridiculous.

Comment: How many potential customers are there? The bit about overbooking makes it sound like there might be more than 300.

Comment: There is something not right about how the question is worded. As Dylan stated, how many people made a reservation? I recognize this problem from a standard stats course. The question would make more sense like: "If the hotel has 300 rooms, the probability per cancellation is 0.15 and 306 people make a reservation, what is the probability that there will be an actual overbooking?"

Comment: This is why I found the question confusing, I'm unsure of the value of n. In part b of the question it asked: "Find the largest number of room reservations that this hotel can book and still be at least 95% sure that everyone who shows up at the hotel will have a room on a given night". Which turned out to be 312. Is this question actually solvable with the information given as it is? I guess part b is what the overbooking is about, but can the probability that at least 6 customers not showing up be found, with the question's current wording?

Comment: If n = 300, (which is not clear) and p = 0.15, there *will* be a near certainty of at least 6 "no shows"

Comment: So if n=300, would my answer be correct? I'm assuming the wording of this question is wrong as it doesn't specify what n actually is as you say.

Comment: Your approach seems correct for your interpretation.  The answer should be close to $1$ unless $n$ is not much larger than $6/0.15 = 40$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)